# Is it possible to add a partition table to an existing AIX ISO?

Tags: boot, partitioning, iso-image, qemu, aix

I've followed this tutorial to run an AIX on an x86 system: https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2019/04/22/installing-aix-on-qemu/

One element of the tutorial is to get an AIX system ISO to install the system. As stated in the tutorial the ISO must have a partition table in order to be boot.

I have a specific ISO that I want to boot on, but this ISO doesn't have a partition table (ok .partitions cdrom returns an empty list). Is there a way to add this partition table to the existing ISO?

Comment: (Also asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629477/is-it-possible-to-add-a-partition-table-to-an-existing-aix-iso -- consider which site you'd like to keep the question on, please)